# CSS: hover over block to change text color and link

Tags: html, css

I have a block `(div)` and which contain text with links.
When I hover over this block I need to change text color (also links color).
"`div:hover`" - with this text color is changed, but link color remain unchanged.

Full code:

CSS:

```
a {
    color: #336699;
}
div {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: red;
}
div a {
    color: red;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: #336699;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    text test <a href="#">URL</a> text
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to target the link explicitly to override its color.

Like this:

```
div:hover a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/c8as1Lv5/)**

**Explanation:**

You originally set the the color of the link to red with:

```
div a {
    color: red;
}
```

When you then add the `div:hover{}` class - although it is a more specific rule than `div a` - it does not target the link itself - only the *container* of the link.

So if there was no rule which set the link color - then the `div:hover{}` class would kick in and color the link white on hover - via *inheritance*.

However since there ***is*** a rule which colors your links red - you need to target the links themselves on hover via the selector `div:hover a`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
div:hover, div:hover a{
            background-color: #336699;
            color: #FFF;
        }
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e1nx20gw/)

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it right. If you need the link to change on hovering the div, you have to do this:

```
div:hover a {
    color: red;
}
```

fiddle here: http://jsbin.com/bipoq/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <style>
         a{
             color: #336699;
          }
          div{
             height: 50px;
             background-color: #FFF;
             color: red;
          }
          div a{
             color: red;
          }
          div:hover{
             background-color: #336699;
             color: #FFF;

          }
          div:hover a
          {
             color: #FFF;
          }

      </style>
  <div>
text test <a href="#">URL</a> text
```