# How can I change the font's text color on hover with CSS in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

Hovering on the webpage works, but NOT as intended. I want the text color to change on hover over a list's item. At this point, the hover changes the color of the text ONLY when hovered over the text, but not on the item itself.

[Vimeo video](https://vimeo.com/444874254)

On the first webpage, it can be seen how the hovering works only on the text itself, and on the second webpage, the color of the text changes when hovered over both list item and text. I want to make the first webpage's side menu just like that. I am using wordpress for the creation of the webpage and custom CSS for styling.

The current CSS code, related to hovering and color change:

```
.et_pb_widget ul li {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 10px;
}

.et_pb_widget ul li:hover {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #ff0000 !important;
}
.et_pb_widget > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #ff0000 !important;
}

.et_pb_widget body:hover {
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

I would really appreciate it if you could help me out with this!

Comment: `.et_pb_widget ul li:hover a{color:#ff000;}`. hover does not need to be the last thing in your selector - put the hover on the li, and the effect on the a. and keep the hover effect on the old selector, that changes the backgroundcolor of the li.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: hover over block to change text color and link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470658/css-hover-over-block-to-change-text-color-and-link) (In your case the `div` is replaced with `li`)

Comment: @Stender it worksss! Big thanks!!!